# print_r return BLANK PAGE

Tags: php, joomla, xampp

I have a weird problem, I am using `print_r($obj)` in Joomla YOOtheme ZOO extension and it returns a blank page. it just act as `die()` !

it should output the object but it does not.

Please note that `print_r()` is working fine with  some other objects and variables.

I am using XAMPP on Windows.

Any help?

Upon executing `print_r()` and `var_dump()`, the page is just blank, no error, view source shows:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Error reporting is turned on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is posible that `$obj` is too big to load, and grabs a lot of memory after which the script stops to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Is error reporting turned on?

If not add to your code:

`ini_set("display_errors", "1");`

Answer (score 3):

If it's outputting nothing, `$obj` contains nothing. Try [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead. Also, make sure you're seeing all errors that PHP is producing:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: the obj has data. the problem is not that print_r is outputting nothing, the problem is that the whole page become blank