# Using var_dump() causes blank page (error reporting is on)

Tags: php, joomla3.0, joomla-template, var-dump

Does anybody have idea why I get blank page when using `var_dump()`?
In the Joomla global config I set up showing errors too. (checked with `phpinfo()` and the local values are on too)

```php
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);  

    $widget_id = $widget->id.'-'.uniqid();
    $settings  = $widget->settings;
    // var_dump($settings);
    // if I uncomment the line above, works fine 
    $sets      = array_chunk($widget->items, $settings['items_per_set']);
    // var_dump($sets); 
    // if I uncomment the line above 
    // and not using the the foreach below
    // blank page appears
    foreach ($sets as $set => $items){
                    var_dump($items);
                      // this line above causes blank page
                        } 

    foreach (array_keys($sets) as $s) {
        $nav[] = '<li><span></span></li>';
    }

    $i = 0;           
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the page show when you remove `var_dump($items)`, then?

Comment: can u make a break point before the foreach ?? var_dump($sets);die(); .. and monitor the results

Comment: @MichaelRushton yes, the page shows up after removing var_dump($items)

Comment: Try viewing the source. Perhaps the dump contains HTML or HTML-like code that destroys the rendering?

Comment: @LeoBali blank page shows up with the breakpoint too

Comment: @MichaelRushton I checked befory, prety empty body tags ..

Comment: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8957608/215384

Comment: @MichaelRushton thank you for your help. I tried before the thread you have mentioned, I posted there my code, and it was deleted. I tried every idea which were spotted there. Maybe the output is too big? hm ...

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` doesn't work if PHP encounters fatal or parse errors. It's best to set `display_errors` in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

Save $items into another variable. Try this

```
 foreach ($sets as $set => $items){
$testvar=$items;
var_dump($testvar);
 // this line above causes blank page
     }
```